# Processing notifications from public, private and shared database in didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: swift, cloudkit, cknotification

I process both private and shared database notifications by converting userInfo to CKDatabaseNotification. But I do get public database notifications also in didReceiveRemoteNotification method and Apple template code does not show how to process it and it raises a fatalError. How can I process public database notifications via my fetchChanges method?

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]
    guard let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? UIViewController else { return }
    guard let notification:CKDatabaseNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:dict) as? CKDatabaseNotification else { return }
    self.fetchChanges(in: notification.databaseScope) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

}

func fetchChanges(in databaseScope: CKDatabaseScope, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    switch databaseScope {
    case .private:
        self.fetchPrivateChanges(completion: completion)
    case .shared:
        self.fetchSharedChanges(completion:) { status in
            if (status == false) {
                return
            }
        }
    case .public:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change `case .public` to `default:` in your `switch` statement since if it's not private or shared, then it must be public.

Also, just to be clear, you don't have to have `fatalError()` in there. If that's what's causing you grief, then remove that and do something with the notification instead.

Another thing I do is check the subscription ID in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to know more about what I should do with it. You can get it like this:

```
if let sub = notification.subscriptionID{
  print(sub) //Prints the subscription ID
}
```

Hopefully that helps. : )

Comment: The issue is if it is public database it would not call fetchChanges since I had a return stateent.

Comment: I changed the code to handle public db like this: if let notification:CKDatabaseNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:dict) as? CKDatabaseNotification {
 self.fetchChanges(in: notification.databaseScope) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
            }
        }
        else  {
            if let notification:CKQueryNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary:dict) as? CKQueryNotification {
                self.processPublicDBChanges(ckqn: notification)
}
  }